# Getting error with using Backslash in Python RE

Tags: python, python-re

```
test_string = "334-33\4455"
match_string = r"^[0-9]{3}-{1}[0-9]{2}[\\]{1}[0-9]{4}"
if re.match(match_string, test_string):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

My output is No. I have tried to escape the Backslash using \ and it is raw string. I am not sure why my pattern is not matching. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `test_string` contains the escape sequence `\4`, not a slash. You need to make that a raw string or use `\\4`

Comment: `{1}` is always redundant.

Comment: There's also no need to put ```\\``` inside `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is correct. what you are missing is the escape character (one more backslash) in your test_tring.

Following code gives you the answer "Yes" for your if condition'

```
import re
test_string = "334-33\\4455" # Have added one more backslash
match_string = r"^[0-9]{3}-{1}[0-9]{2}[\\]{1}[0-9]{4}"
if re.match(match_string, test_string):
  print("Yes")
else:
  print("No")
```